# Pick nodes evenly distance from each other

Tags: igraph, graph-theory, network-analysis

In **igraph** is there a common way to pick such nodes in a graph so that they will be evenly (or as good as possible) spaced from each other?

I imagine it like some force-layout, but instead of doing it in 2D space it needs to be done in "graph-space".

In other words, need to pick a set **B** of nodes of graph **A** so that paths between closest neighbors of **B** will be as long as possible. **B** will be way smaller than **A**: something like 20 nodes in a 4 million nodes graph.

Comment: Do you know how many nodes you want to select (how large **B** should be)? The [`farthest_points`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#farthest_points) function will give you two points that are as far as possible in the graph, thus technically satisfying your problem statement.

Comment: @PidgeyUsedGust **B** supposed to be ~20, so I guess `farthest_points()` won't help ...